# Como posso tirar a primeira diferença do PPC para cada país?

Tags: r

eu estou fazendo um trabalho de econometria e gostaria de tirar a primeira diferença da Paridade do Poder de compra para os países em que estou analisando. O problema é que a base está em formato long, agrupada para os países, mas agora não sei como posso realizar o diff condicionando as informações?

```
# Dados
library(readxl)
PPC.World.Bank <- read_excel("Desktop/FGV EESP/Econometria 2/Data_Extract_From_World_Development_Indicators.xlsx")
View(PPC.World.Bank)

#Pacotes
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(reshape2)

#Filtragem e Organização dos dados

  #Renomeando colunas
colnames(PPC.World.Bank) <- c( 
  "Series Name", "Series Code", "Country Name", "Country Code","1994","1995",
  "1996","1997","1998","1999","2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006",
  "2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017",
  "2018","2019","2020","2021","2022")

  # Reovendo linhas em branco
PPC.1 = slice(PPC.World.Bank, 1:4)
View(PPC.1) 

  #Formato long
PPC.long <-melt(PPC.1)
View(PPC.long)

  #Renomeando colunas
colnames(PPC.long) <- c( 
  "Series Name", "Series Code", "Country Name", "Country Code","Ano", "Paridade do Poder de Compra")
Ano = PPC.long$Ano
PPC = PPC.long$`Paridade do Poder de Compra`

#Gráficos
graf.1.ppc = ggplot(data = PPC.long, mapping =aes(x = Ano, y = PPC, group = 1))+
  geom_line(size = 0.5)+ #queremos um gráfico de linhas
  geom_point(color = "Dark Red", size = 0.8) + facet_wrap(~PPC.long$`Country Name`, scales ='free_y') +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks =c('1994','1999','2004','2009','2013','2017', '2021'))+
  xlab('Ano')+
  ylab('')+
  ggtitle('Variação da Paridade do Poder de Compra na América Latina')+
  theme_hc() +
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(1, 'cm'))

    #Gráfico Interativo
library(plotly)
graf.1.ppc <- ggplotly(graf.1.ppc)
graf.1.ppc

#Aplicando a primeira diferença (??????)
PPC.long$D.PPC <- c(diff(PPC.long$`Paridade do Poder de Compra`[PPC.long$`Country Name` == 'Brazil']))
```

```
#Dados

  Country Name Country Code  Ano Paridade do Poder de Compra
1         Brazil          BRA 1994                   0.5186519
2       Colombia          COL 1994                 416.0606291
3          Chile          CHL 1994                 318.0708270
4         Mexico          MEX 1994                   2.5233760
5         Brazil          BRA 1995                   0.8375032
6       Colombia          COL 1995                 489.2790238
7          Chile          CHL 1995                 332.0346800
8         Mexico          MEX 1995                   3.2874370
9         Brazil          BRA 1996                   0.9418661
10      Colombia          COL 1996                 574.2037233
11         Chile          CHL 1996                 337.8788510
12        Mexico          MEX 1996                   4.2009140
13        Brazil          BRA 1997                   0.9841012
14      Colombia          COL 1997                 664.6783632
15         Chile          CHL 1997                 344.2524390
16        Mexico          MEX 1997                   4.8611370
17        Brazil          BRA 1998                   1.0000209
18      Colombia          COL 1998                 776.7906741
19         Chile          CHL 1998                 353.3377630
20        Mexico          MEX 1998                   5.4995960
21        Brazil          BRA 1999                   1.0261538
22      Colombia          COL 1999                 842.8132316
23         Chile          CHL 1999                 357.2808230
24        Mexico          MEX 1999                   6.2246400
25        Brazil          BRA 2000                   1.0625565
26      Colombia          COL 2000                 890.4723000
27         Chile          CHL 2000                 363.4930230
28        Mexico          MEX 2000                   6.7508860
29        Brazil          BRA 2001                   1.1040372
30      Colombia          COL 2001                 935.0151684
31         Chile          CHL 2001                 373.5080360
32        Mexico          MEX 2001                   6.9152720
33        Brazil          BRA 2002                   1.1786367
34      Colombia          COL 2002                 978.8812648
35         Chile          CHL 2002                 381.0144050
36        Mexico          MEX 2002                   7.2375840
37        Brazil          BRA 2003                   1.3220601
38      Colombia          COL 2003                1025.4050898
39         Chile          CHL 2003                 382.5364820
40        Mexico          MEX 2003                   7.3441190
41        Brazil          BRA 2004                   1.3725329
42      Colombia          COL 2004                1057.6024091
43         Chile          CHL 2004                 380.3494520
44        Mexico          MEX 2004                   7.4658230
45        Brazil          BRA 2005                   1.4186871
46      Colombia          COL 2005                1074.5689477
47         Chile          CHL 2005                 387.3600000
48        Mexico          MEX 2005                   7.6483310
49        Brazil          BRA 2006                   1.4318482
50      Colombia          COL 2006                1085.6711396
51         Chile          CHL 2006                 338.4908630
52        Mexico          MEX 2006                   7.7403490
53        Brazil          BRA 2007                   1.4428266
54      Colombia          COL 2007                1114.0917494
55         Chile          CHL 2007                 343.1078220
56        Mexico          MEX 2007                   7.9550070
57        Brazil          BRA 2008                   1.4683860
58      Colombia          COL 2008                1147.9895518
59         Chile          CHL 2008                 360.3642160
60        Mexico          MEX 2008                   8.1585910
61        Brazil          BRA 2009                   1.5456568
62      Colombia          COL 2009                1200.4853878
63         Chile          CHL 2009                 367.5612430
64        Mexico          MEX 2009                   8.4331810
65        Brazil          BRA 2010                   1.5973411
66      Colombia          COL 2010                1207.9398723
67         Chile          CHL 2010                 373.2912300
68        Mexico          MEX 2010                   8.7250210
69        Brazil          BRA 2011                   1.6512214
70      Colombia          COL 2011                1210.9931641
71         Chile          CHL 2011                 370.1987370
72        Mexico          MEX 2011                   8.9402120
73        Brazil          BRA 2012                   1.6626555
74      Colombia          COL 2012                1189.5036621
75         Chile          CHL 2012                 391.5723640
76        Mexico          MEX 2012                   9.2234710
77        Brazil          BRA 2013                   1.7916766
78      Colombia          COL 2013                1220.9112549
79         Chile          CHL 2013                 390.1613030
80        Mexico          MEX 2013                   9.1808920
81        Brazil          BRA 2014                   1.9007571
82      Colombia          COL 2014                1249.0191650
83         Chile          CHL 2014                 410.6707420
84        Mexico          MEX 2014                   9.3536260
85        Brazil          BRA 2015                   2.0829582
86      Colombia          COL 2015                1305.7772217
87         Chile          CHL 2015                 447.2666320
88        Mexico          MEX 2015                   9.4335910
89        Brazil          BRA 2016                   2.2490232
90      Colombia          COL 2016                1403.3064550
91         Chile          CHL 2016                 452.9225690
92        Mexico          MEX 2016                   9.4599330
93        Brazil          BRA 2017                   2.3273771
94      Colombia          COL 2017                1467.2812320
95         Chile          CHL 2017                 463.2314130
96        Mexico          MEX 2017                  10.1353830
97        Brazil          BRA 2018                   2.3551456
98      Colombia          COL 2018                1464.4117980
99         Chile          CHL 2018                 458.3124900
100       Mexico          MEX 2018                  10.3514900
101       Brazil          BRA 2019                   2.3995772
102     Colombia          COL 2019                1516.4399870
103        Chile          CHL 2019                 465.2358790
104       Mexico          MEX 2019                  10.7914090
105       Brazil          BRA 2020                   2.4464668
106     Colombia          COL 2020                1529.9317530
107        Chile          CHL 2020                 469.0956380
108       Mexico          MEX 2020                  10.7418270
109       Brazil          BRA 2021                   2.5306766
110     Colombia          COL 2021                1567.4466590
111        Chile          CHL 2021                 477.8180280
112       Mexico          MEX 2021                  11.0856900
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui estão duas maneiras diferentes de calcular as diferenças anuais de PPC.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

res1 <- PPC.long %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  arrange(Ano) %>%
  mutate(DiffPPC = `Paridade do Poder de Compra` - lag(`Paridade do Poder de Compra`, default = 0))

res2 <- PPC.long %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  arrange(Ano) %>%
  mutate(DiffPPC = c(first(`Paridade do Poder de Compra`), diff(`Paridade do Poder de Compra`)))

identical(res1, res2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Dados

```r
PPC.long <- read.table(text = "
 Country Name 'Country Code'  Ano 'Paridade do Poder de Compra'
1         Brazil          BRA 1994                   0.5186519
2       Colombia          COL 1994                 416.0606291
3          Chile          CHL 1994                 318.0708270
4         Mexico          MEX 1994                   2.5233760
5         Brazil          BRA 1995                   0.8375032
6       Colombia          COL 1995                 489.2790238
7          Chile          CHL 1995                 332.0346800
8         Mexico          MEX 1995                   3.2874370
9         Brazil          BRA 1996                   0.9418661
10      Colombia          COL 1996                 574.2037233
11         Chile          CHL 1996                 337.8788510
12        Mexico          MEX 1996                   4.2009140
13        Brazil          BRA 1997                   0.9841012
14      Colombia          COL 1997                 664.6783632
15         Chile          CHL 1997                 344.2524390
16        Mexico          MEX 1997                   4.8611370
17        Brazil          BRA 1998                   1.0000209
18      Colombia          COL 1998                 776.7906741
19         Chile          CHL 1998                 353.3377630
20        Mexico          MEX 1998                   5.4995960
21        Brazil          BRA 1999                   1.0261538
22      Colombia          COL 1999                 842.8132316
23         Chile          CHL 1999                 357.2808230
24        Mexico          MEX 1999                   6.2246400
25        Brazil          BRA 2000                   1.0625565
26      Colombia          COL 2000                 890.4723000
27         Chile          CHL 2000                 363.4930230
28        Mexico          MEX 2000                   6.7508860
29        Brazil          BRA 2001                   1.1040372
30      Colombia          COL 2001                 935.0151684
31         Chile          CHL 2001                 373.5080360
32        Mexico          MEX 2001                   6.9152720
33        Brazil          BRA 2002                   1.1786367
34      Colombia          COL 2002                 978.8812648
35         Chile          CHL 2002                 381.0144050
36        Mexico          MEX 2002                   7.2375840
37        Brazil          BRA 2003                   1.3220601
38      Colombia          COL 2003                1025.4050898
39         Chile          CHL 2003                 382.5364820
40        Mexico          MEX 2003                   7.3441190
41        Brazil          BRA 2004                   1.3725329
42      Colombia          COL 2004                1057.6024091
43         Chile          CHL 2004                 380.3494520
44        Mexico          MEX 2004                   7.4658230
45        Brazil          BRA 2005                   1.4186871
46      Colombia          COL 2005                1074.5689477
47         Chile          CHL 2005                 387.3600000
48        Mexico          MEX 2005                   7.6483310
49        Brazil          BRA 2006                   1.4318482
50      Colombia          COL 2006                1085.6711396
51         Chile          CHL 2006                 338.4908630
52        Mexico          MEX 2006                   7.7403490
53        Brazil          BRA 2007                   1.4428266
54      Colombia          COL 2007                1114.0917494
55         Chile          CHL 2007                 343.1078220
56        Mexico          MEX 2007                   7.9550070
57        Brazil          BRA 2008                   1.4683860
58      Colombia          COL 2008                1147.9895518
59         Chile          CHL 2008                 360.3642160
60        Mexico          MEX 2008                   8.1585910
61        Brazil          BRA 2009                   1.5456568
62      Colombia          COL 2009                1200.4853878
63         Chile          CHL 2009                 367.5612430
64        Mexico          MEX 2009                   8.4331810
65        Brazil          BRA 2010                   1.5973411
66      Colombia          COL 2010                1207.9398723
67         Chile          CHL 2010                 373.2912300
68        Mexico          MEX 2010                   8.7250210
69        Brazil          BRA 2011                   1.6512214
70      Colombia          COL 2011                1210.9931641
71         Chile          CHL 2011                 370.1987370
72        Mexico          MEX 2011                   8.9402120
73        Brazil          BRA 2012                   1.6626555
74      Colombia          COL 2012                1189.5036621
75         Chile          CHL 2012                 391.5723640
76        Mexico          MEX 2012                   9.2234710
77        Brazil          BRA 2013                   1.7916766
78      Colombia          COL 2013                1220.9112549
79         Chile          CHL 2013                 390.1613030
80        Mexico          MEX 2013                   9.1808920
81        Brazil          BRA 2014                   1.9007571
82      Colombia          COL 2014                1249.0191650
83         Chile          CHL 2014                 410.6707420
84        Mexico          MEX 2014                   9.3536260
85        Brazil          BRA 2015                   2.0829582
86      Colombia          COL 2015                1305.7772217
87         Chile          CHL 2015                 447.2666320
88        Mexico          MEX 2015                   9.4335910
89        Brazil          BRA 2016                   2.2490232
90      Colombia          COL 2016                1403.3064550
91         Chile          CHL 2016                 452.9225690
92        Mexico          MEX 2016                   9.4599330
93        Brazil          BRA 2017                   2.3273771
94      Colombia          COL 2017                1467.2812320
95         Chile          CHL 2017                 463.2314130
96        Mexico          MEX 2017                  10.1353830
97        Brazil          BRA 2018                   2.3551456
98      Colombia          COL 2018                1464.4117980
99         Chile          CHL 2018                 458.3124900
100       Mexico          MEX 2018                  10.3514900
101       Brazil          BRA 2019                   2.3995772
102     Colombia          COL 2019                1516.4399870
103        Chile          CHL 2019                 465.2358790
104       Mexico          MEX 2019                  10.7914090
105       Brazil          BRA 2020                   2.4464668
106     Colombia          COL 2020                1529.9317530
107        Chile          CHL 2020                 469.0956380
108       Mexico          MEX 2020                  10.7418270
109       Brazil          BRA 2021                   2.5306766
110     Colombia          COL 2021                1567.4466590
111        Chile          CHL 2021                 477.8180280
112       Mexico          MEX 2021                  11.0856900
", header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)

str(PPC.long)
#> 'data.frame':    112 obs. of  5 variables:
#>  $ Country                    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>  $ Name                       : chr  "Brazil" "Colombia" "Chile" "Mexico" ...
#>  $ Country Code               : chr  "BRA" "COL" "CHL" "MEX" ...
#>  $ Ano                        : int  1994 1994 1994 1994 1995 1995 1995 1995 1996 1996 ...
#>  $ Paridade do Poder de Compra: num  0.519 416.061 318.071 2.523 0.838 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigada!!!! Só mais uma dúvida, onde eu teria que alterar no código pr tirar a segunda diferença?

Comment: @CarolHesser Com a função `dplyr::lag` é o argumento `n = 2`; com a função base `diff` é `lag = 2`.